# How do I customise the appearance of links in QLabels using style sheets?

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qlabel

I have a `QLabel` with a Qt stylesheet that sets a dark background:

```
QLabel {
background: black;
color: white;
}
```

This works fine until I add text with an embedded URL and set the `Qt::TextFormat` to `Qt::RichText`.  The link displays as the default dark blue, which is hard to read on a dark background.

I've tried customising it via a stylesheet such as:

```
a { color: white; }
QLabel!visited { color: white; }
```

but this doesn't have any effect.  The one thing that does seem to work is changing the application's `QPalette`:

```
QPalette newPal(qApp->palette());
newPal.setColor(QPalette::Link, Qt::white);
newPal.setColor(QPalette::LinkVisited, Qt::white);
qApp->setPalette(newPal);
```

However this requires the colour to be hardcoded.  Is there any way I can set the colour from a stylesheet instead?

EDIT:

I've discovered a further problem with customising the palette.  If I want to just modify the palette of my widget (substituting `widget` for `qApp` in the sample above) then this doesn't work.  I don't want to affect all the other `QLabels` in the app, so how do I limit the palette changes to this widget?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer is no. Recently I had to do this.

1. `QLabel!visited` doesn't work because Qt doesn't track whether QLabel were visited or not.
2. `QLabel { color: ... }` doesn't work for links. Can't find why but all I found is a suggestion to use `QPallete` in this case.

Comment: I think I've come to the same conclusions - see my other comment

Comment: QLabel().setText('<a href="..link"><span style="color:white;">something</span>')

Answer (score 14):

One way is to add `style="color: whatever"` or a class to the inner `<span>` of the link. I haven't figured out yet how to apply this to the whole application but it's a good start.

Comment: This is the only actual answer. Note that the Qt designer seems to explicitly colour each link, which overrides any default in your global stylesheet.

Comment: A slight simplification here is to add the styling to the anchor tag directly: `<a href="..." style="color: whatever">...</a>`. Note that this answer isn't about stylesheets so it doesn't answer the original question... Useful though.

Answer (score 7):

I've had little success explicitly setting the `QPalette` -- it works if you set it for the entire application, but not if you set it in the widget.  In the end though, the easiest thing for what I needed to do was use a [QTextBrowser](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtextbrowser.html) instead which supports a [subset](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/richtext-html-subset.html) of HTML.  I could then override the colour of links using a regular CSS stylesheet:

```
QTextBrowser browser;
// IMPORTANT! - set the stylesheet before the content
browser->document()->setDefaultStyleSheet("a {color: white; }");
browser->setText(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the color tag in the HTML to

```
{ color: inherit; }
```