# Qt stylesheet, how to set color of QPalette::Link and QPlatte::LinkVisited

Tags: qt, hyperlink, stylesheet, qtstylesheets

I use a library which uses colors of QPalette::Link and QPalette::LinkVisited as background and border color for a widget.
I would like to change these colors with stylesheet. How can I set color of Link and LinkVisited with help of stylesheet?

I have read, that qt doesn't support LinkVisited option for links. But in my case both colors are used not for link, but for some parts of the widget.

I would like to use stylesheet instead of setting color of QPalette. But it seems that it's impossible to set that colors with stylesheet. Is it true?

I want to set color for a Widget. I can use this code:
    `QPalette p;`
    `p.setColor(QPalette::Link, QColor(0,255,0));`
    `p.setColor(QPalette::LinkVisited, QColor(0, 255, 0));`
    `pWidget->setPalette(p);`

But I want to do the same with a stylesheet. For example something like this:
   `QWidget { link-color: green; link-visited-color: green;}`

Comment: Do you want to set colors of the QPallette or the QWidget that you need styling, in the later case you can definitely set colors for your widget through style sheet ? Need more information

Comment: I have added more explanation.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can set the `background-color` & `color` attributes of your widget as follows, forget the `QPallette`:

```
QWidget#yourWidgetName
{
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #1c1c1c;
}
```

Read the [documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/stylesheet-examples.html) A-Z, it has all the wisdom you gonna need when dealing with QT style-sheets

Setting `link-color` & `link-visited-color` at the style-sheet level is not possible though.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, but how can I set the color of Link and LinkVisited with stylesheet?

Comment: Actually, I found a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497799/how-do-i-customise-the-appearance-of-links-in-qlabels-using-style-sheets[link]  
And the answer: "it's impossible" :)

Comment: Me too think, that is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Same as you I could not found a proper way of doing that using the stylesheet or QPalette.

But for my needs to control the color I used this method, of setting `<span>` inside of the `<a>` to control to color.

```
QLabel().setText('<a href="..link"><span style="color:white;">something</span>')
```

Answer (score -1):

It's the wrong place to set it. Links are a part of the document, not of the browser and QWidgets are more or less browsers.

Comment: QWidgets are not browsers, not even from a far away point of view. Qwidgets have not content document.